# Stop Excel from evaluating cell contents?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function

Is there a way to stop Excel 2010 from doing math on a bunch of cells containing multiple numbers with leading plus or minus signs? E.g.

```
-706795 -1456130 -1869550 -936304 -1729830 -1737860 -687165 -16807800
```

Right now it sums the numbers up into one value. I would like them displayed as above. Formatting the cell as text doesn't work. I get this data from a CSV and have limited control over its contents...

Comment: Can you not get the text import wizard to load each value into an individual column?

Comment: Good question, that actually got me on the right track. It won't give me the import wizard by default when I open a CSV file but if I rename it to .txt then I have control over formatting the columns and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, that's an even better alternative that works. Thank you!

Comment: [format as `Text`](http://superuser.com/questions/641248/how-to-tell-excel-not-to-evaluate-a-formula/641271#641271)

or 

use a single quote: `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the text import wizard to load each value into an individual column.  You may have to rename the CSV file as '.txt' to get the import wzard up by default, (shameless rep seeking here:).

Answer (score 6):

Use a single quote

```
'-706795 -1456130 -1869550 -936304 -1729830 -1737860 -687165 -16807800
```

Comment: I have several hundreds of such cells, editing them all manually would be a pain.