# How do you stop Excel from casting cells starting with "MARxxxx" as alphabetically first

Tags: excel, sorting, formatting

[image: screenshot of excel]

Everything that starts with "MAR" is sorting alphabetically first

Pictured, is Row 2 with MAR2290, hidden rows with other MAR courses, and then a row with ABE4231C in Row 90.

I'm trying to sort in alphabetical order courses at a university and Marketing courses (MAR) come up before everything else (even those that start with the letter "A").

I've tried formatting the cell as text, but that still doesn't sort properly.

[Stop Excel from evaluating cell contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886418/stop-excel-from-evaluating-cell-contents) is helpful as a workaround, but still doesn't allow a true sort

Comment: It shouldnt happen, but may I know have you entered those data manually or have you imported externally, if so then are you sure is there any unwanted non breakable characters, that could be one of the reason why it is sorting wrongly.

Comment: This was imported from a SQL database export

Comment: Yes that could be one of the reasons, it is carrying the non printable characters along with it, you can use a formula to remove those characters, `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(160),)` and then sort

Comment: That didn't change the sorting there. I will note that going into the cell (hitting F2) and then enter changes the cell to a date (3/1/2290) displayed in the cell as "Mar-90"

Comment: Yes that is one possible reason it turns to date, so while importing can you import them as text?

Comment: I'll look around the SQL Developer app settings to see what I can find for the export (I'm using mostly default settings to export as .xlsx).

Comment: I appreciate your time looking into this with me

Comment: Yeah that will be better, if you can make changed in the `SQL Developer`